# binded object with temp editing in svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have this svelte repl as an example of what I'm trying to do :

https://svelte.dev/repl/91d21e1baa564ecea6afbc4df7d9d24c?version=3.23.2

The goal is to have a two way binding but with the way from Component to App controlled / triggered with a button.

The simple way bypasses due to the direct referencing of the object.
However, cloning the object blocks the way back from Component to App.

I am quite confused and can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks for helping.

**EDIT** Original code

`App.svelte`

```
<script>
    import Component from "./Component.svelte";
    let object = {name: "project"};
</script>

<h1>Main</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={object.name} />
<hr>
<Component bind:object={object} />
```

`Component.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let object;
    //$: tempObject = object;
    $: tempObject ={...object};
</script>

<h1>Component</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={tempObject.name} />
<button type="button" on:click={() => object = tempObject}>Save</button>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! When you post a link to some code, please also post a copy of the relevant parts in the question, for future reference (if the link becomes broken, etc.).

Comment: thx rixo, your answer helped me a lot. Plus, I'll take your comment for next submission. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you need an intermediary object to do that.

What you must be careful is to not update the source object when the local copy is modified.

Here's a way to do it:

`Component.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let object

    let local

    const update = () => {
        local = { ...object }
    }

    const commit = () => {
        object = local
    }

    // when source object changes, update local
    //
    // /!\ local must be appear in this reactive block, 
    //     or the update will loop back
    //
    $: object, update()
</script>

<h1>Component</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={local.name} />
<button type="button" on:click={commit}>Save</button>
```

The important point is that the `local` variable must **not** appear in the reactive block that propagates changes from the source to the local copy. Or you'll get a kind of update loop.

In order to do that, replace the `local = {...object}` assignment with a function (`update` in the example) that you'll call from the reactive block. This way the `local` variable itself can be affected without Svelte rerunning the reactive block when its value changes.